# How to define snapshot.data type in FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I specify the data type of `snapshot.data` in a `FutureBuilder`? For example, in the following snippet, I anticipate the future to yield a list. However, invoking `snapshot.data.length` results in an error because the type of `snapshot.data` is inferred as `Object?`, not as a list.

How can I explicitly define the expected type for `snapshot.data`?

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: locator<UniversityApi>().getUniversities,
  builder: (context, snapshot) => ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.length, // Error: The method 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object?'
  ),
),
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the snapshot type like this:

```
FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>( // replace dynamic with your type
  future: locator<UniversityApi>().getUniversities
  builder: (context, snapshot) => ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: snapshot.data.length, //this line should work now
  ),
),
...
```

Just be careful, before using `snapshot.data.length` you should make sure that snapshot contains any data:

```
FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>( // replace dynamic with your type
  future: locator<UniversityApi>().getUniversities
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
       return ListView.builder(
         itemBuilder: snapshot.data.length,
       );
    }

    return SizedBox(); // Return any placeholder widget
  }
),
...
```